# What is second Parameter in 1DConv output shape keras Model Summary?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am training 1DConv model, having 4248 instances and 39249 features in each instance. I am trying VGG16 model with 32 batch size, but after 7 layers it returns the following error.

Negative dimension size caused by substracting  3 from 1 for conv1d_8/convolution/Conv2D (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,1,1,256] , [1,3,256,512].

To debug further, I have printed the full network using keras model.summary(). Image is attached. I have two concerns.

1. Why am I getting the negative dimension error?
2. I have seen that the second parameter in output shape goes to 2 in conv1d_7 layer and further substraction is not possible. What is second parameter? I have gone through [this](https://blog.goodaudience.com/introduction-to-1d-convolutional-neural-networks-in-keras-for-time-sequences-3a7ff801a2cf) document and I have found that the second parameter is obtained using the following formula (Height -Kernel Size + 1), and represents the number of steps window will slide through the data. Kernel Size in my case is 3 and I am confused about height. The document explains that 'height is the length of one dataset which is fed into the network'. Does the length refer to the input number of features, or batch size* number of input features? How 11250 is calculated in output shape of first layer. Below is my code (I am able to calculate parameters for the rest of the layer, only second parameter is confusing, previous posts explain how to calculate params not about the length of data).
3. For such huge features (39249) per sample and only around 4k instances, which deep learning algorithm might be useful in accurate classification?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
model = Sequential()
 model.add(Conv1D(filters = 8, kernel_size=3, strides=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_timestamps,n_features)))

 model.add(Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, strides=3, activation='relu'))
 model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2,strides=2))

 model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=3, activation='relu'))
 model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2,strides=2))

 model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=3, activation='relu'))
 model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2,strides=2))
 model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=3, activation='relu'))
 model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2,strides=2))

 model.add(Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=3, activation='relu'))
 model.add(Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=3, activation='relu'))
 model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4,strides=3))
 print(model.summary())

 model.add(Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, strides=3, activation='relu'))
 model.add(Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, strides=3, activation='relu'))
 model.add(Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, strides=3, activation='relu'))
 model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2,strides=2))
 print(model.summary())

 model.add(Conv1D(filters=512, kernel_size=3, strides=3, activation='relu'))
 model.add(Conv1D(filters=512, kernel_size=3, strides=3, activation='relu'))
 model.add(Conv1D(filters=512, kernel_size=3, strides=3, activation='relu'))
 model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2,strides=2))
 print(model.summary())

 model.add(Conv1D(filters=512, kernel_size=3, strides=3, activation='relu'))
 model.add(Conv1D(filters=512, kernel_size=3, strides=3, activation='relu'))
 model.add(Conv1D(filters=512, kernel_size=3, strides=3, activation='relu'))
 model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2,strides=2))

 model.add(Flatten())
 model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
 #model.add(Dropout(0.5))
 model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
 #model.add(Dropout(0.5))
 model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax'))
 print(model.summary())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-Here we have a problem with strides = 3 in each layers. its means after each convolution filter the feather_size changes to feather_size/3 and its cause to reduce your feather_size fast.
I suggest you decrease stride of filters. for example strides = 1 seems appropriate.

2-As a general formula you can calculate the size of output feather after each Conv. filter by ((feather_size - kernel_size)/stride) + 1

At the end, for more description of each parameters in convolution filter in keras, I can refer you to https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/

Answer (score 1):

1) Any operation that reduces your output feature map, will be the culprit of negative dimension error. Usually, it occurs due to 'valid' padding, pooling, or strides.

"VALID" = without padding:

```
   inputs:         1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 (12 13)
                  |________________|                dropped
                                 |_________________|
```

"POOLING" = 2x2 max-pooling, take only 1 maximum value from 2by2 window, so the output shape is halved each time it is applied.

As these operations reduce the shape of your feature map, there is a chance, in a layer, the feature map is just too small, even smaller than the size of a single kernel, so you can't apply those operations anymore, hence this error.

2) You have used a high stride value so, the length of your feature map drops faster. You can follow any blog to get the idea on how to calculate each parameter, https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-and-calculating-the-number-of-parameters-in-convolution-neural-networks-cnns-fc88790d530d

3) You can simply reduce the number of neurons in your Dense or FC layers. Try with smaller units such as 512 instead of 4096 and see how the accuracy drops. Add a few batch-norm layers and increase dropout so that no overfitting occurs.